# While loop in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

I wrote this assembly program to add lengths together until user enters 0. Length should be changed to inches or feet depending on user input (' for feet and " for inches). I have it detecting the user input correctly, but I can't get it to keep looping. I put asteriks(*) around the part that I think works for detecting if the user entered a 0 or not.

```
.data 
enter: .asciz "Enter a measurement and unit(Ex: 4' or 3\"; 0' or 0\" when done): "
read: .asciz "&value"
inches: .asciz " inches"
total: .asciz "Total: "

.text
############################ main() ##############################

.global main
main:
# Your code goes here!
 pushq %rbp
 movq %rsp, %rbp
 subq $16, %rsp
 movl $0, -4(%rbp)

.L1:
 movl $enter, %edi
 movl $0, %eax
 call printStr
 leaq -12(%rbp), %rdx
 leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
 movl $read, %eax
 call readUInt
 movl %eax, -8(%rbp)
 call getchar
 movl %eax, -12(%rbp)
 movl -12(%rbp), %eax
 cmpl $39, %eax
 jne .L2
 movl -8(%rbp), %edx
 movl %edx, %eax
 addl %eax, %eax
 addl %edx, %eax
 sall $2, %eax
 addl %eax, -4(%rbp)
 jmp .L3

.L2:
 movl -12(%rbp), %eax
 cmpl $34, %eax
 jne .L3
 movl -8(%rbp), %eax
 addl %eax, -4(%rbp)

.L3:
 **movl -8(%rbp), %eax
 testl %eax, %eax
 jne .L1**
 movl $total, %edi
 call printStr
 movl -4(%rbp), %edi
 call printUInt
 movl $inches, %edi
 call printStr
  leave
  ret
```

Around the asteriks(*) is the part I test the user input(if it's a 0). So it's like a DO_WHILE loop. Anyway, if anyone has any possible solutions or advice, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: It's not clear how `readUint` works. Does it stop reading characters when it finds a non-numeric character, or when it finds a carriage return?

Comment: @Michael readUInt() returns unsigned integers from stdin. I assume it does stop reading when it finds a non-numeric character. getchar() returns the NEXT character(in this case, single or double quotes)

Comment: You should probably make sure that that's how it works (e.g. try printing the value returned by `readUint`). If it keeps reading until it finds a CR it might bail out when it sees a `'`/`"` and return some default value (like 0).

Comment: @Michael just tested it. It prints only the integer even if I add any characters after it.

Comment: @Michael So what should i do? I am restricted to using only these functions since it's a project.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger? Usually examing the registers after each instruction is very educational about what your program *really* does, as opposed to what you think it does.  (As you get more experienced, you will learn how to "step throught the code" symbolically in your head.  In the meantime, you probably need help. Debuggers help. A lot.).

Comment: I've never used it but I can try it. I'm just running out of time here.

Comment: @IraBaxter I found that typing numbers without a quote symbol will keep the while loop going. But once I type a quote symbol after the number, it ends the loop. So not sure how I could go about parsing this since it's required that the user enters the quote after the number (or zero to end, of course). So the quote symbol is returning a value of zero which is causing it to end. How else can I go about solving this?

Comment: It is unlikely that experimenting to death with the input will let you see your problem, until you get more mature with simulation-in-your-head, and that's unlikely to happen to in the next day or two.  Get thee to a debugger.  You are wasting time, trying to avoid this step.  Even experts resort to this "trick".

Comment: I've already tried the debugger and it won't work because I'm using external functions(from an object file) that it doesn't recognize. Honestly it wouldn't tell me anything I don't already know. I already know that getchar() will override readUInt() after it's called and store the character's value(ZERO) into %eax. I just can't figure out how to keep the value initially entered by the user through the loop when every time the getchar() will change it to zero because of the quote. It's fine though, I knew it was a longshot anyone would try to help but I'll stick with what I have and turn it in.

Comment: @Jay:  You are wrong about a) the debugger not "working" [being useful]; you don't have the experience to judge, and b) it won't tell you anything you don't know [that's the point of using a debugger, is to find out if what the code does, is what you think it does.  Usually it doesn',t but you can't see that without help].  Sorry you didn't get somebody to just hand you the answer.  I tried instead to teach you how to fish.  Its too bad you don't think of that as help.

Comment: @IraBaxter You're right, I eventually got around to getting the debugger to work. I only come here for help AFTER I've put in countless hours in to a project (had many sleepless nights to get where I was at for this one) and have no choice but to ask for other opinions. I apologize for insulting your intelligence, take care.